# Angular table directive ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hy,

I created a directive for a simple use of tables in my application.
I'm struggling to get an ng-repeat to work.
The problem is that my directive  will tell the table from what controller it will get the list with the data for the ng-repeat and this seems not to work, i could use another directive to create an ng-repeat but i don´t want to change the way the developer can use the angular directives.

So if anyone already struggled with this problem please share how you resolve it.

this is the markup.

```
<body ng-app="List">
<div my-table pl-emptytext="No data found!">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th pl-sort="Id"> Id </th>
        <th pl-sort="Name"> Name </th>
        <th pl-sort="Roles"> Roles </th>
        <th pl-sort="Claims"> Claims </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr pl-obj="user">
        <td>{{user.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
        <td>
          <span ng-repeat="role in user.Roles">
            {{role.RoleType}}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span ng-repeat="claim in user.Claims">
            {{role.ClaimType}}
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the directive myTable

```
angular
.module('List')
.directive('myTable', [
  '$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restriction: 'AE',
      scope: {
        plEmptytext: '@'
      },
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div class="container-fluid">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-lg-12">' +
        '<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-cloak ng-show="ListIsEmpty">' +
        '{{plEmptytext}}' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        // Do something else, bind events, etc ...

        var table = element.find('table');
        $compile(table)(scope);
      }
    };
  }
])
.directive('table', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$addClass("table");
        attrs.$addClass("table-striped");
      }
    };
  }
])
.directive('thead', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  }
])
.directive('th', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (attrs.plSort) {
          attrs.$set("ngClick", "resort('" + attrs.plSort + "')");
        }
      }
    };
  }
])
.directive('tbody', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$set("ng-controller", "listCtrl");

      }
    };
  }
])
.directive('tr', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (attrs.plObj) {
          attrs.$set("ngRepeat", attrs.plObj + " in List");

        }
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

And this is the listCtrl

```
angular.module('List', [])
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.List = [{
        Id: '1',
        Name: 'teste1',
        Roles: [{
          Id: 1,
          RoleType: '1'
        }, {
          Id: 2,
          RoleType: '2'
        }],
        Claims: [{
          Id: 1,
          CalimType: '1'
        }, {
          Id: 2,
          ClaimType: '2'
        }]
      }, {
        Id: '1',
        Name: 'teste1',
        Roles: [{
          Id: 2,
          RoleType: '2'
        }],
        Claims: [{
          Id: 2,
          ClaimType: '2'
        }]
      }];
    }, 1000)
  }
]);
```

The problem is when i try to call the ng-repeat on this 2 td it dosen´t work

```
<td>
  <span ng-repeat="role in user.Roles">
    {{role.RoleType}}
  </span>
</td>
<td>
  <span ng-repeat="claim in user.Claims">
    {{role.ClaimType}}
  </span>
</td>
```

Anyone can point me in the direction of the problem? Already look to different things and different solutions from different people, yet it seems that no one had face my problem.

Best,

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pfw5X8hV7foZxgGspyiu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `pl-obj` directive is literally just an `ng-repeat`. So use `<tr ng-repeat="user in List">`.

Second of all, your controller doesn't appear to be hooked up. You're trying to hook it up using a strange directive, but you may be doing it in a way Angular doesn't understand (properties of the `attrs` object are camelCased, not hyphen-ated). Just use an `ng-controller` attribute on your `table` element: `<table ng-controller="listCtrl">`.

Once you're using more standard Angular in this way, I expect your problem will be easier to troubleshoot.

EDIT: Here's a Plunker with the changes I recommended (and some corrected typos). https://plnkr.co/edit/iEEtBycevB3Wh6eHFEAI?p=preview. Seems to work fine now.

EDIT 2: If you want to use the same controller for all `<tbody>` (I don't recommend this, but it's something you can do), use this in your directive:

```
function() {
  return {
    controller: 'listCtrl',
    ...
  };
}
```

Comment: The change you made to use ng-repeat instead of the pl-obj i can accept but the change to use ng-controller on the element table is not what i need. There will be several controllers attached to the table one on header other on body and others to control other elements that will be attached to the table. And it is not just to put all the ng-controllers on the place i want, i want to hide this from all the tables markup since they will be the same for all the tables that i can introduce on my project. But i would give the same answer as you to an user that have done the question that i did. +1

Comment: That makes sense. Hopefully my answer gets you a little closer to what you're trying to do. If I were you, I would use self-contained isolated-scope directives instead of stopgap directives that try to add controllers after the fact (the directive object can contain a "controller" property as well as the "link" property you're using). It's the Angular way to do it.

Comment: You are right pls update your answer to in the directive `tbody` use `return{ controller: 'listCtrl', ....}` so i can mark it as correct

Comment: Done. The reason I don't recommend it is because `tbody` is a tag built into HTML, so if you make it into a directive, anyone else who works with your code and wants to build a table may end up very confused about why certain things are happening. But it is something you can do.

Comment: That will not happen the tag tbofy will only match if it is part of the main directive in this example `myTable` So if everyone can use my solution and use tbodys anywhere as long that they aren´t children of myTable.

Comment: I think it may be worthwhile to test that theory. Any `<tbody>` element inside of an element where `ng-app="List"` should have that directive applied to it, whether or not it is a child of a `myTable` directive.